# Difference between DataControl.cpx and Datacontrol.dcx in Oracle ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

In Oracle ADF what is the difference between `DataControl.dcx` and `DataControl.cpx` ? What goes where ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the doc at [A.7 DataBindings.cpx](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15586_01/web.1111/b31974/appendixa.htm#CDJBBHIH)

Answer (score 1):

**Databindings.cpx- Data Binding Registry**
Jdeveloper Creates this first time when you data bind a UI Component
It has
**pageMap** maps all user interface URLs and the corresponding page definition usage name. This map is used at runtime to map a URL to its page definition.
**pageDefinitionUsages** maps a page definition usage (BindingContainer instance) name to the corresponding page definition. The id attribute represents the usage ID. The path attribute represents the full path to the pagedefinition.
**dataControlUsages** declares a list of data control usages (shortnames)corresponding path to the data control definition entries is available in datacontrols.dcx file

**Datacontrols.dcx  -Data Controls Registry**
Lists ADF Data control available in a project
It Contains Information needed to initialize the data control to work with. a particular service (Java bean web service ,EJB) J developer Creates this file when you create a data control . This file is not generated for Oracle ADF Business Components